# Having problems changing shortcut keys combination for input source

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, text-input, input-source

Good morning everybody!
I'm trying to change the keyboard combination keys for my input source from "control+space" to "command+space" but it wont budge.
System prefrences instructs: "To change a shortcut, select it, click the key combination, and then type the new keys. Now, either im an idiot, or this just dosent work. any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You now need to click again on the shortcut alone at the far right.  Then you will be able to enter a new shortcut by typing it.