# Settings on keyboard shortcuts to switch input sources do not sustain

Tags: macos, catalina, shortcut, input-source

I would like to use control+space to switch input methods in MacOS Catalina. Every time in the Keyboard/Input sources settings I check both boxes but after rebooting they become unchecked. How can I fix this problem?

(Image from this question: [Having problems changing shortcut keys combination for input source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257058/having-problems-changing-shortcut-keys-combination-for-input-source))
[image]

Comment: What happens when you press Ctrl-Space or Ctrl-Alt-Space after the reboot but before reassigning either?

Comment: @Alper nothing happens.